# Ext.app.application object is erased after initialization

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to organize an existing extjs code in a more standard order (extjs wise).

extjs version: extjs-4.0.2a.

I've worked through the Extjs tutorial example and every thing went well.

When I started working on the company's code I've notice there is no use of the application object there for I've added the Ext.application({...}); call.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'FOO',
    appFolder: 'appFolderName', 
    launch: function() {    
        console.log('application was created');
    }
});
```

Upon loading the page I see the console.log output that is included in the "launch" function property - meaning the application object is created but when I look for it ("FOO" object) under the "window" object it is not there. Compering to the tutorial code the application object exist as a property of window.
I encounter a few loading problems but I'm guessing the source of it all is this issue.

What am I doing wrong?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it yourself. Add line `FOO.app = this;` inside the `launch` function.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'FOO',
    appFolder: 'appFolderName',
    launch: function() {
        FOO.app = this;
        console.log('application was created');
    }
});
```